# Save the output of transform XML with XSLT 2.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-serialization, xslt-2.0

I want to transform an xml file in other xml. I want to use XSLT 2.0, process the file and the output should be saved in another file. I would like to trigger the transformation per command line tool. Which processor XSLT 2.0 can I install to achive that, if it is possible.

Comment: Well, there aren't so many stand-alone XSLT 2 processors on the market, Saxon 9 HE is open-source and comes in a .NET version or a Java version and C/C++ version.  XmlPrime is a .NET implementation but for commercial use requires buying a license.

Comment: Can I trigger a transformation process with Saxon 9  without writing any tool in c# or java?

Comment: Sure, the command line interface is documented at http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/using-xsl/commandline/ so it is alike `transform.exe -s:input.xml -xsl:sheet.xsl -o:result.xml` for .NET or `java -jar saxon9he.jar -s:input.xml -xsl:sheet.xsl -o:result.xml`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't like seeing unanswered questions, so to recap what's already in the comments: One option is to download Saxon (either an open-source or commercial version), ensure that Java is installed, and then run the transformation from the command line using

```
java -jar saxon9he.jar -s:input.xml -xsl:sheet.xsl -o:result.xml
```